# What would be a built-in alternative to using RestSharp for the following code?

Tags: c#, postman, httprequest, httpclient

I have a requirement to send the following but using built in .net classes, HttpClient preferably.

I tried with Httpclient, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage and SendAsync but I get errors of missing json while calling it with same params from Postman works fine.

Maybe I am using the wrong classes. Thanks

```
    var client = new RestClient("myurl");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("channelId", "mytestid");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "big access token");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\n  \"jsonrequesthere\":...}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
var client = new HttpClient(); // ideally this would be created from IHttpClientFactory
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "myurl");

request.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.Headers.Add("channelId", "mytestid");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "big access token");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

request.Content = new StringContent(json, null, "application/json");
// or request.Content = JsonContent.Create(SomeObjectToSerialize);

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

<sub>***Note** : There are many other built in ways to achieve the same thing. Though at this stage in your learning you are better to just read the documentation*</sub>

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vm4wfW)

Comment: Thanks I was doing that before and still failing when I realized I was passing wrong json keys... but your code is cleaner, thanks!

Comment: @RollRoll all good, glad it helps. Also remember if you have tried something, its always best to paste that in the question :)